Python project architecture venv
In a lot of my python projects, i use a self written class: Logger. Quite simple, it print the given argument to the screen or saves it to disk. Like: Logger.log('some text'). In some applications I want to use Logger.log_header('header text'), in others Logger.log_columns('value 1', 'value 2').
My projects have their own project and virtual environment, the Logger as well. What is the best architecture in this kind of scenario's? Should every project have the Logger class version, in 'reach' of the projects venv? Or should I just add the by the Logger used modules to the project venv?
What is the best way to store your projects anyway? One root directory 'Project' and subdirs for every project with their own venvs?
Kind regard, Willem-Jan
I use separate projects for the application and the Logger. This creates errors, because the Application venv, doesn't know the use import libraries for the Logger.
